# Suggestions for improvement in answering and encouragement

Tags: discussion, support

I didn't receive any answers for my question. Is it common while having low reputation?

I am sure it's one of the most interesting questions... Because of the low reputation (below 15) I can't do anything here.

Comment: You just asked it an hour ago.  Learn some patience.

Comment: Most people don't care (much) about the reputation of the person asking; instead they care about question quality. Do look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers and see if your question can be improved still.

Comment: And *1 hour* is hardly a long enough time to wait for answers. Some patience goes a long way too!

Comment: @fbueckert ty for ur comment here .. i ll wait .. but it happens offen

Comment: @MartijnPieters ty for ur reply here ..my question may quality they upvote  .. then wts the purpose for down vote

Comment: @user3563106 If you find that your questions are frequently not being answered then it likely means you're questions are not of great quality.  Consider spending more time making them clearer.  There are lots of places to find information all around the site as to how to improve the quality of your questions, if you don't know how to make them better.

Comment: Are you talking about [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23565288/change-default-name-of-tools-into-our-own-in-ajax-tools)? If that's the case, I would make clearer that I'm looking for some sort of type alias, and would change the last line. `I know its possible, but need to know the step of process and example code to achieve this` diminishes the incentive to answer IMHO.

Comment: @user, okay, I tried to improve the question for you. I hope I did not butcher it too much, and that it stills conveys your original point. Leave me a note there if it doesn't.

Comment: Stack Overflow receives ten to twenty thousand new questions per day, and it may be worth noting (in the spirit of Robert Thorn) that "Stack Overflow is people!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, as per the comments, it's very common for answers to take several hours at least.  Don't take it personally.

If you *really* want people to answer your question, wait for two days, pay your dues by answering other questions on the site, and then you can award some of your reputation as a bounty to the answerer.  That tends to wake people up, especially on obscure topics.  If your question is unclear, hopefully people will write comments asking for clarification or valuable feedback on how to post better.  (I'm not sure which question you asked, which would be helpful information here.)

If your question is very basic and you can't find it on Stack Overflow, other Users' flags of questions that are duplicates might help point you in the right direction.  I also suggest IRC chat channels for common programming languages.